# Azure SQL Server Connection Error Despite Correct Credentials - Error Number:18456,State:1,Class:14

Tags: sql-server, database, azure, connection

I have created a new SQL Database on Azure, and have copied the connection string directly from the Azure Portal.

On my .NET application, when I am trying to run 'Update-Database' command in Package Manager Console to commit the migration, I receive the following error:

> Error Number:18456,State:1,Class:14 Login failed for user
>
> 'benhayward'.

---

**Extra Information:**
- I have changed my database admin password.
- I have confirmed that the log-in credentials are correct.
- I am on the Azure free trial.

Any advice or assistance on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you open the firewall for your client IP on the database?

Comment: @silent yes I did this during the initial set up, thank you for your response.

Comment: @BenHayward can you use the account/login  "benhayward" connect to Azure SQL database with SSMS?  Please replace the password `Password={your_password}` in the Connection string.

Comment: @LeonYue Hi there, yes I can login via SSMS which makes this particularly strange, I can confirm also that my password is used in the connection string in that format.

I tried to make another database and I am having the same problems there too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok a slightly embarrassing solution, but the reason this wasn't working is because of the curly brackets surrounding the password, as LeonYue suggested.

Comment: You're welcome,you can mark it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The problem was that I had two entirelly different connection strings with the same name in different config files. The right one in app settings was being overwritten by another connection string in my user secrets. As soon as I deleted connection string from my secrets, everything went fine without any errors. Hope my solution will help the others